# 2001 toyota corolla electric window goes up half way then pushes outward and stops

Tags: toyota, corolla, power-windows

my 2001 toyota corolla driver side window goes up half way then pushes outward and binds up then stops. What is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the regulator is worn out and will need to be replaced. I wouldn't try to force it up, or you could shatter the glass. The slides for the glass could also be at fault. Some windows incorporate both the slides and the regulator together ... some do not.